# WPConnect.exe is missing from my computer

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have been trying to run the application with capture and photo choosers task but seems like i can't run it with zune running and i should run **WPConnect.exe** but i cant find it. can we download it manually? or else? help

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure to grab the tools update. I believe this will come with the tools once the Mango tools are out fully. But prior to Mango, check out this little guide:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/03/tips-for-debugging-wp7-media-apps-with-wpconnect.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you **do not** have the Mango (7.1) SDK installed, the location is

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Tools\WPConnect\x86\WPConnect.exe
```

If you **do** have the Mango (7.1) SDK installed, the location is

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x86\WPConnect.exe
```

And obviously if you run 64-bit Windows, the location is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Tools\WPConnect\x64\WPConnect.exe
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x64\WPConnect.exe
```